# How to target a field in Prisma and get a flat array of values rather than an array of objects

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I just started using Primsa 2 so I am still a noob at this but all I am trying to do is create a flat array of strings(`Array<number>`) based on the values I get from a specific field. Right now when I target that field it gives me an array of objects like this: `userIds: [{ issueId: 1, userId: 1 }]`

All I want is the value I get from the `userId` key and the array to return like this `userIds: [ 1 ]`. I was able to fix this with some formatting code after the query which was done like so:

```
const issues = project.issues.map(issue => ({ ...issue, userIds: [...issue.userIds.map((id) => id.userId)] }))
const _project = { ...project, issues }
```

However, this doesn't seem like the most optimal solution. If this is the only way that is fine but I assume with the power that Prisma has for querying, this is something I can do just in the query alone?

For reference, my query currently looks like this:

```
const project = await prisma.project.findFirst({
  where: { id: req.currentUser.projectId },
  include: { users: true, issues: { include: { userIds: true } } },
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your schema? Perhaps you can model the relation differently. However, unless if you provide a field, `userIds`, that is a flat array and not a field of a an other relation it will be returned as a list of objects as you have already.